# chartjs multiple lines datasets perfomance issue

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have scatter chart with many lines that share single x with multiple y and it looks like chart with many separate lines with different colors.

Consider chart data with single dot like
{x: 195
y0: 0
y1: 0
y2: 0
y3: 0
y4: 0 }
consisting of thousands such dots in single array.

For chartjs I need to add each dataset for each line and parse it to tell what exact y should each line use

```
   const datasets = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < yCount; i++) {
        datasets.push(
            {
                data: preparedData,
                showLine: true,
                borderColor: `${COLORS[i]}`,
                fill: false,
                borderWidth: 1,
                parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: 'x',
                    yAxisKey: `y${i}`
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

It works BUT we put giant amount of `preparedData` into each item of an array. That drastically affects perfomance. Is there any solution, for example single source of truth for all datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having Chart.js parsing your `preparedData`, you could do it on your own.
A slight improvement can then be obtained if you parse the `x` values only once and assign them to `data.labels` using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows.

```
labels: preparedData.map(o => o.x)
```

Then you can detect all non-`x` properties from your data objects and map them to `datasets`.

```
datasets: Object.keys(preparedData[0])
  .filter(k => k != 'x')
  .map((k, i) => ({
    label: k,
    data: preparedData.map(o => o[k]),
    showLine: true,
    borderColor: colors[i],
    tension: 0.2
  }))
```

Please take a look at the runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'gray', 'purple'];
const preparedData = [
  { x: 195, y0: 2, y1: 1, y2: 2, y3: 2, y4: 0 },
  { x: 200, y0: 3, y1: 3, y2: 3, y3: 4, y4: 2 },
  { x: 230, y0: 1, y1: 0, y2: 1, y3: 3, y4: 3 },
  { x: 245, y0: 2, y1: 3, y2: 1, y3: 4, y4: 1 },
  { x: 260, y0: 3, y1: 2, y2: 3, y3: 2, y4: 4 },
  { x: 290, y0: 1, y1: 2, y2: 4, y3: 1, y4: 0 }
];

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    labels: preparedData.map(o => o.x),
    datasets: Object.keys(preparedData[0])
      .filter(k => k != 'x')
      .map((k, i) => ({
        label: k,
        data: preparedData.map(o => o[k]),
        showLine: true,
        borderColor: colors[i],
        tension: 0.2
      }))
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```